# Akka TCP IO sends me connect message twice

Tags: scala, tcp, akka

I have a simple client server program
The server listens as follows

```
val manager = IO(Tcp)    
manager ! Bind(self, myAddress,1,options)
```

Then in receive loop

```
override def receive = {
case b @ Bound(addr) => 
      {
       log.info("bound")
       myAddress = addr       
       bBound = true
      }
case c @ Connected(remoteAddress,localAddress) => 
log.info("Client Connected. Remote: {} Local: {}", remoteAddress, localAddress)
myAPAddress = remoteAddress
remoteConnection = sender()
remoteConnection ! Register(self,keepOpenOnPeerClosed=true)
//first thing to do is to register yourself with a lookup
mLookupManager ! AddMe(myAddress, this.context.self.path)
```

However the connect message is being received twice.
The server actor is not getting restarted as I have overloaded preRestart and it is not getting called. The problem is that the lookup manager looks up and if finds an actorpath with same socket address then sends a poison pill to it. And then adds new actor to it.
However In this case it kills the same actor and adds it's actorpath
Why would I get the connect message twice? Any clue?

Comment: I think I found the problem. My basic tests are showing good results. If someone can confirm if this is really an issue, it will help. Here's what I did -                        On the client side, I was first registering and then writing something back. This write was happening in the connect message. There were 2 writes. I removed one of them. And this solved the issue. Now I get only 1 connect message in the server. Is there any recommendation that in the client side connect message, we should not use TCP ! write more than once?

Answer (score 0):

When `Bind` has successfully completed (you got `Bound` back) the server actor it will get a `Connect` message for every new connection that is made to the socket.

The common pattern is to let the `Connect` message trigger creation of a new actor who will be responsible for interacting with that specific client, rather than having the "server" actor doing the interaction.

See the docs here for a sample that does exactly that: http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.4.14/scala/io-tcp.html#Accepting_connections

Comment: Hi, I was expecting the same. i.e. "the server actor it will get a Connect message for every new connection that is made to the socket. " However, I was getting 2 connect messages even for a single client connection.